# Android Volume Button Listener when Screen Off

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, volume, onkeydown

I have an activity listening for volume button events using onKeyDown(), however I am not able to see these events when the screen is off.

Is there any way I can still listen for volume button presses when the screen is off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, This is not possible usually because broadcast receiver not work when screen light off because after screen off your volume button get lock and volume level not change.

**Alternative Way to do this:**

But you can achieve using run Media Player with zero sound in background infinite times that keep your volume button active always or you can use Wake Lock to achieve this.

But I don't suggest to do this method of long time because it totally drain the battery very fast. You can use these alternative method to do this for short period of time otherwise mobile battery get down fastly.

Comment: Would it be possible using a wake lock?  The media volume definietly changes when the volume buttons are pressed so I would think we would be able to listen for this?

Comment: @lrAndroid I mentioned this above in my answer. check it.

Answer (score -2):

If you wish to control the volume of audio played through your app, make use of setVolumeControlStream() method. It directs volume key presses to the audio stream you specify.

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

However, if you wish to make the volume button a shortcut key for your app, I'm afraid there is no straightforward solution.

Comment: This isn't helpful as I already know how to control the volume when the user is in the app.  I'm trying to control the volume when the screen is off.